# How to handle array coming back from an AJAX call?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, arrays

I am trying to handle an array coming back from an ajax call.  My current situation is a button gets clicked, and when clicked, it fires an ajax call.  Here is a snippet of the PHP after ajax has been called..

```
function count_total() {
    $count = get_count();
    if ($count == 0) {
        $count = 1; 
    }
    $total = get_total();
    $response = array('count' => $count, 'total' => $total);
    echo $response;
    exit;
}
```

Ok so now this $response variable is passed back to the JS side and if I alert the variable obviously it will say "Array".  So my question is, how can I work with this array?  I am trying to get the key/value out?

Or I can't pass an array to it like that?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your echo to be this.

```
echo json_encode($response);
```

and then instead of alerting the response, parse it with a json parser library [like this](http://www.json.org/js.html).

Then you will have a true javascript **object** not an array because you're using a associative array.

Answer (score 0):

PHP isn't sending back the array itself, just the word 'Array'. It can only send back plain text/HTML (or files if you mess with headers).

Look into either using JSON or an equivalent method that will take an array and put it into a text form to be recovered in JavaScript or roll your own.

For example you could echo "count=12;total=254" from PHP and use JavaScripts split() function to break it back into it's parts.